# Removing a category and adding datapoints in ggplot2

Tags: r

I am trying to develop a boxplot using the following sample code:

```
a <- ggplot(na.omit(dataframe), aes(x=Type, y=X_cells, fill=as.factor(response))) + 
  geom_boxplot() 
a + ggtitle("Sampletext") + 
   ylab("X cells") + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Response", labels = c("Negative", "Positive")) + 
   theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", hjust=0.5))
```

However, this results in a plot with a total of 6 categories on the x-axis, where each category has 2 boxes (one for positive and one for negative) yielding a total of 12 boxplots. The 6th category is extra displayed as '0' in the axis that I would like to remove. Is this possible?

Also, is there a way to display datapoints in the boxplots for both Positive and Negative boxes?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and/or the resulting graphic?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out how many levels your variable `Type` has with `str(dataframe$Type)` and either check if the 6th category is based on some issue in your data setup or just exclude it with e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe_new <- filter(dataframe, Type != "0")
```

you can also use `filter(dataframe, Type != "0")` within your ggplot function to not create a new dataframe and then try to replot it (however it is hard to say if the exact code works without seeing the actual dataset; so you might have to adapt the `""` term).

In order to visualize datapoints you can add the term `+ geom_point(position = position_jitterdodge()` and then just adjust it to your preferences.

Comment: @ Tim Schauer thanks, this worked well. I was wondering if there is a way to change the colour of the dots for datapoints to match the ones used in Positive and Negative boxplots but without fill? By default these were green and red respectively.

Comment: Your are welcome! Yes you can just use the call `colour = "red"` within the `geom_point()` phrase and adapt the color either by name or the hex code to match the color of the boxplots. However, all those small adaptions are easy to look up in R help page. And if the comment was answering your question, could you please accept it?